# Carrierwave cache_stored_file! does not fetch the file in the cache

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, fog

I am migrating from Carrierwave 1.3.X to 2.2.X and I am running into trouble here and there. One of the snippets that fail for me is this:

```rb
def files
  signable_template.signable_documents.map do |sd|
    sd.document.cache_stored_file!
    sd.document.file.to_file
  end
end
```

The above method should return an array of files. Instead, it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
2023-07-04 23:12:24.058569 F [57069:puma threadpool 001 thread_local_var.rb:93] Rails -- Exception: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_file' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000001601b54c0 @uploader=#<SignableDocumentDocumentUploader:0x000000014ffdc1e0 @model=#<SignableDocument id: 1064252880, signable_template_id: 1064252880, account_id: 511176957, document: "offer.docx", preview: "preview.pdf", kind: "offer", created_at: "2023-07-04 09:06:30.424573000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-07-04 09:06:54.011485000 +0000">, @mounted_as=:document, @staged=true, @file=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000001601b54c0 ...>, @filename="offer.docx", @cache_id="1688501542-652153691939222-0003-6859", @identifier="offer.docx", @versions={}, @versions_to_cache=nil, @versions_to_store=nil, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x000000014dd1fe18 @uploader=#<SignableDocumentDocumentUploader:0x000000014ffdc1e0 ...>, @connection=#<Fog::AWS::Storage::Real:205320 @use_iam_profile=nil @instrumentor=nil @instrumentor_name="fog.aws.storage" @connection_options={:retry_limit=>5, :retry_interval=>1, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :persistent=>false} @persistent=false @acceleration=false @signature_version=4 @enable_signature_v4_streaming=true @path_style=false @max_put_chunk_size=5368709120 @max_copy_chunk_size=5368709120 @disable_content_md5_validation=false @region="us-east-1" @endpoint=nil @host="s3.amazonaws.com" @scheme="https" @port=443 @aws_credentials_refresh_threshold_seconds=nil @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" @aws_session_token=nil @aws_credentials_expire_at=nil @signer=#<Fog::AWS::SignatureV4:0x0000000149cb4108 @region="us-east-1", @service="s3", @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX", @hmac=#<Fog::HMAC:0x000000014cc978c0 @key="YYYYYYYYYYYYY", @digest=#<OpenSSL::Digest: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855>, @signer=#<Proc:0x000000014cc97488 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:28 (lambda)>>> @connection=#<Fog::XML::Connection:0x000000014ddf6940 @path_prefix=nil, @excon=#<Excon::Connection:689e8 @pid=57069 @data={:chunk_size=>1048576, :ciphers=>"ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS", :connect_timeout=>60, :debug_request=>false, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :idempotent=>false, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :middlewares=>[Excon::Middleware::ResponseParser, Excon::Middleware::Expects, Excon::Middleware::Idempotent, Excon::Middleware::Instrumentor, Excon::Middleware::Mock], :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :omit_default_port=>false, :persistent=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_errors=>[Excon::Error::Timeout, Excon::Error::Socket, Excon::Error::HTTPStatus], :retry_limit=>5, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :ssl_uri_schemes=>["https"], :stubs=>:global, :tcp_nodelay=>false, :thread_safe_sockets=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :versions=>"excon/0.99.0 (arm64-darwin21) ruby/3.2.2", :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :hostname=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"", :port=>443, :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :retry_interval=>1} @socket_key="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443" @_excon_sockets={#<Thread:0x000000014f11b9d0 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/logging-2.3.1/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471 sleep>=>{}} @persistent_socket_reusable=true @httplog_url="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443">>>>, @original_filename="offer.docx", @cache_storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x000000014ddf9dc0 @uploader=#<SignableDocumentDocumentUploader:0x000000014ffdc1e0 ...>, @connection=#<Fog::AWS::Storage::Real:205320 @use_iam_profile=nil @instrumentor=nil @instrumentor_name="fog.aws.storage" @connection_options={:retry_limit=>5, :retry_interval=>1, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :persistent=>false} @persistent=false @acceleration=false @signature_version=4 @enable_signature_v4_streaming=true @path_style=false @max_put_chunk_size=5368709120 @max_copy_chunk_size=5368709120 @disable_content_md5_validation=false @region="us-east-1" @endpoint=nil @host="s3.amazonaws.com" @scheme="https" @port=443 @aws_credentials_refresh_threshold_seconds=nil @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" @aws_session_token=nil @aws_credentials_expire_at=nil @signer=#<Fog::AWS::SignatureV4:0x0000000149cb4108 @region="us-east-1", @service="s3", @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX", @hmac=#<Fog::HMAC:0x000000014cc978c0 @key="YYYYYYYYYYYYY", @digest=#<OpenSSL::Digest: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855>, @signer=#<Proc:0x000000014cc97488 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:28 (lambda)>>> @connection=#<Fog::XML::Connection:0x000000014ddf6940 @path_prefix=nil, @excon=#<Excon::Connection:689e8 @pid=57069 @data={:chunk_size=>1048576, :ciphers=>"ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS", :connect_timeout=>60, :debug_request=>false, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :idempotent=>false, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :middlewares=>[Excon::Middleware::ResponseParser, Excon::Middleware::Expects, Excon::Middleware::Idempotent, Excon::Middleware::Instrumentor, Excon::Middleware::Mock], :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :omit_default_port=>false, :persistent=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_errors=>[Excon::Error::Timeout, Excon::Error::Socket, Excon::Error::HTTPStatus], :retry_limit=>5, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :ssl_uri_schemes=>["https"], :stubs=>:global, :tcp_nodelay=>false, :thread_safe_sockets=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :versions=>"excon/0.99.0 (arm64-darwin21) ruby/3.2.2", :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :hostname=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"", :port=>443, :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :retry_interval=>1} @socket_key="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443" @_excon_sockets={#<Thread:0x000000014f11b9d0 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/logging-2.3.1/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471 sleep>=>{}} @persistent_socket_reusable=true @httplog_url="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443">>>>>, @base=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x000000014ddf9dc0 @uploader=#<SignableDocumentDocumentUploader:0x000000014ffdc1e0 @model=#<SignableDocument id: 1064252880, signable_template_id: 1064252880, account_id: 511176957, document: "offer.docx", preview: "preview.pdf", kind: "offer", created_at: "2023-07-04 09:06:30.424573000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-07-04 09:06:54.011485000 +0000">, @mounted_as=:document, @staged=true, @file=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000001601b54c0 ...>, @filename="offer.docx", @cache_id="1688501542-652153691939222-0003-6859", @identifier="offer.docx", @versions={}, @versions_to_cache=nil, @versions_to_store=nil, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x000000014dd1fe18 @uploader=#<SignableDocumentDocumentUploader:0x000000014ffdc1e0 ...>, @connection=#<Fog::AWS::Storage::Real:205320 @use_iam_profile=nil @instrumentor=nil @instrumentor_name="fog.aws.storage" @connection_options={:retry_limit=>5, :retry_interval=>1, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :persistent=>false} @persistent=false @acceleration=false @signature_version=4 @enable_signature_v4_streaming=true @path_style=false @max_put_chunk_size=5368709120 @max_copy_chunk_size=5368709120 @disable_content_md5_validation=false @region="us-east-1" @endpoint=nil @host="s3.amazonaws.com" @scheme="https" @port=443 @aws_credentials_refresh_threshold_seconds=nil @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" @aws_session_token=nil @aws_credentials_expire_at=nil @signer=#<Fog::AWS::SignatureV4:0x0000000149cb4108 @region="us-east-1", @service="s3", @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX", @hmac=#<Fog::HMAC:0x000000014cc978c0 @key="YYYYYYYYYYYYY", @digest=#<OpenSSL::Digest: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855>, @signer=#<Proc:0x000000014cc97488 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:28 (lambda)>>> @connection=#<Fog::XML::Connection:0x000000014ddf6940 @path_prefix=nil, @excon=#<Excon::Connection:689e8 @pid=57069 @data={:chunk_size=>1048576, :ciphers=>"ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS", :connect_timeout=>60, :debug_request=>false, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :idempotent=>false, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :middlewares=>[Excon::Middleware::ResponseParser, Excon::Middleware::Expects, Excon::Middleware::Idempotent, Excon::Middleware::Instrumentor, Excon::Middleware::Mock], :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :omit_default_port=>false, :persistent=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_errors=>[Excon::Error::Timeout, Excon::Error::Socket, Excon::Error::HTTPStatus], :retry_limit=>5, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :ssl_uri_schemes=>["https"], :stubs=>:global, :tcp_nodelay=>false, :thread_safe_sockets=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :versions=>"excon/0.99.0 (arm64-darwin21) ruby/3.2.2", :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :hostname=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"", :port=>443, :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :retry_interval=>1} @socket_key="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443" @_excon_sockets={#<Thread:0x000000014f11b9d0 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/logging-2.3.1/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471 sleep>=>{}} @persistent_socket_reusable=true @httplog_url="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443">>>>, @original_filename="offer.docx", @cache_storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x000000014ddf9dc0 ...>>, @connection=#<Fog::AWS::Storage::Real:205320 @use_iam_profile=nil @instrumentor=nil @instrumentor_name="fog.aws.storage" @connection_options={:retry_limit=>5, :retry_interval=>1, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :persistent=>false} @persistent=false @acceleration=false @signature_version=4 @enable_signature_v4_streaming=true @path_style=false @max_put_chunk_size=5368709120 @max_copy_chunk_size=5368709120 @disable_content_md5_validation=false @region="us-east-1" @endpoint=nil @host="s3.amazonaws.com" @scheme="https" @port=443 @aws_credentials_refresh_threshold_seconds=nil @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" @aws_session_token=nil @aws_credentials_expire_at=nil @signer=#<Fog::AWS::SignatureV4:0x0000000149cb4108 @region="us-east-1", @service="s3", @aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX", @hmac=#<Fog::HMAC:0x000000014cc978c0 @key="YYYYYYYYYYYYY", @digest=#<OpenSSL::Digest: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855>, @signer=#<Proc:0x000000014cc97488 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/fog-core-2.3.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:28 (lambda)>>> @connection=#<Fog::XML::Connection:0x000000014ddf6940 @path_prefix=nil, @excon=#<Excon::Connection:689e8 @pid=57069 @data={:chunk_size=>1048576, :ciphers=>"ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS", :connect_timeout=>60, :debug_request=>false, :debug_response=>true, :headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"fog-core/2.3.0"}, :idempotent=>false, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :middlewares=>[Excon::Middleware::ResponseParser, Excon::Middleware::Expects, Excon::Middleware::Idempotent, Excon::Middleware::Instrumentor, Excon::Middleware::Mock], :mock=>false, :nonblock=>true, :omit_default_port=>false, :persistent=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_errors=>[Excon::Error::Timeout, Excon::Error::Socket, Excon::Error::HTTPStatus], :retry_limit=>5, :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :ssl_uri_schemes=>["https"], :stubs=>:global, :tcp_nodelay=>false, :thread_safe_sockets=>true, :uri_parser=>URI, :versions=>"excon/0.99.0 (arm64-darwin21) ruby/3.2.2", :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :hostname=>"development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com", :path=>"", :port=>443, :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :retry_interval=>1} @socket_key="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443" @_excon_sockets={#<Thread:0x000000014f11b9d0 /Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/logging-2.3.1/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471 sleep>=>{}} @persistent_socket_reusable=true @httplog_url="https://development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443">>>>, @path="/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/tmp/uploads/1688501542-652153691939222-0003-6859/offer.docx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", @directory=  <Fog::AWS::Storage::Directory
    key="development-workable",
    creation_date=nil
  >, @file=  <Fog::AWS::Storage::File
    key="/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/tmp/uploads/1688501542-652153691939222-0003-6859/offer.docx",
    cache_control=nil,
    content_disposition=nil,
    content_encoding=nil,
    content_length=7492,
    content_md5=nil,
    content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    etag="89e41846773950a5f9d87204e1c4f9e0",
    expires=nil,
    last_modified=nil,
    metadata={"x-amz-id-2"=>"vvikP7WPUo1vhrkZ2ZPMbsc4fR4Sh3ylVltijYAjwi3Cx03wH0pew1k6Y4aJUcNci9KXoujfdns=", "x-amz-request-id"=>"QF7MP3YK0X5MF9EA"},
    owner=nil,
    storage_class=nil,
    encryption="AES256",
    encryption_key=nil,
    version=nil,
    kms_key_id=nil,
    tags=nil,
    website_redirect_location=nil
  >>
/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/app/services/offers/previewer.rb:27:in `block in files'
/Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:88:in `each'
/Users/markosfragkakis/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:88:in `each'
/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/app/services/offers/previewer.rb:23:in `map'
/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/app/services/offers/previewer.rb:23:in `files'
/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/app/services/offers/previewer.rb:15:in `preview_token'
```

I tried to understand why this happens, so I set a byebug breakpoint and run some snippets:

```
[20, 29] in /Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/app/services/offers/previewer.rb
   20:     end
   21: 
   22:     def files
   23:       signable_template.signable_documents.map do |sd|
   24:         byebug
=> 25:         sd.document.cache_stored_file!
   26:         sd.document.file.to_file
   27:       end
   28:     end
   29: 
(byebug) sd.document.cache_stored_file!
2023-07-04 23:42:34.253693 I [68127:puma threadpool 001] HttpLog -- [httplog] Connecting: development-workable.s3.amazonaws.com:443
2023-07-04 23:42:35.056167 I [68127:puma threadpool 001] HttpLog -- { :method => "HEAD", 
...
# the file is downloaded successfully with status code 200
....
(byebug) sd.document.file.path
"/Users/markosfragkakis/dev/workable/tmp/uploads/1688503355-677970767411897-0001-8361/offer.docx"
# Looks correct, BUT this file doesn't exist in the filesystem!
(byebug)         sd.document.file.to_file
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `to_file' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000001211197a8 @uploader=#<SignableDocumentDocumentUploader:0x0000000123bb6420 @model=#<SignableDocument id: 1064252880, signable_template_id: 1064252880, account_id: 511176957, document: "offer.docx", preview: "preview.pdf", kind: "offer", created_at: "2023-07-04 09:06:30.424573000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-07-04 09:06:54.011485000 +0000">, @mounted_as=:document, @staged=true, @file=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000001211197a8 ...>, @filename="offer.docx", @cache_id="1688503355-677970767411897-
...
...
...
```

In my understanding, the result of the `sd.document.file.path` is supposed to be the path to the file downloaded in the cache. Although this seems to be a legit path, the file doesn't actually exist in the filesystem. I guess this is the root cause for the following error, with the `undefined method` to_file'`.

Any idea why this code doesn't work with Carrierwave 2.2.X? Note that it works with carrierwave 1.3.X. Carrierwave 3.0.0 was released a couple of days ago, but it gives the same error.

For completion, this is the relevant model and uploader:

```rb
class SignableDocument < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :document, SignableDocumentDocumentUploader
...
end
```

```rb
class SignableDocumentDocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include UploaderWithFilenamesSanitizable

  def self.fog_public
    false
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/signable_documents/#{model.account_id}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w[docx]
  end
end
```

Comment: `CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File` have not ever have `#to_file` method. As I think if you switch back to CarrierWave 1.3.3 and check the class of the object returned by `sd.document.cache_stored_file!` it probably would be `SanitizedFile`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

`#to_file` method was recently [added](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/269c37a6c8609c26915f31ccfada512ef12fb3cb/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb#L457-L464) to CarrierWave 3.x.

According to its source (and common sense though) you could apply the same logic directly in your code:

```rb
def files
  signable_template.signable_documents.map do |sd|
    sd.document.cache_stored_file!
    ::File.open(sd.document.file.path)
  end
end
```